# mysql connection error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) Godaddy Cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, localhost, hosting

My website was working fine till yesterday. But it suddenly started showing this error:

> mysql connection error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through
>   socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

I don't think I made any changes except adding the site to alexa. I googled this and found a lot of resources but all those couldnt help me because I did not fully understand them. I am also not able to locate the file `mysql.sock`.

I want to know if my website has been hacked. Plus, the solution to the problem.

Comment: Does anyone else have access to your website? Also do you have a backup of your website? If not some hosting services provide backups, depending on where you host they could have a backup. Try to reach out to them.

Comment: Can you access your database using phpmyadmin or mysql workbench? I would start trying to see if the issue is in the database or in the site. We need to narrow things down because it can be many things.

Comment: This error is a hosting based error , if you have vps / ssh access to your server then you have to solve it with those details , it has nothing to do with your site coding , just try to restart your mysql server and check also if it's running or not

Comment: @RandallValenciano When i try to access db using phpmyadmin it gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

Might want to start with checking all your db configuration and make sure you did not overwrite or accidentally changed something?

If not that, then try restarting your mysql server. Not sure what Linux env your running, but whichever one it is, Google how to restart mysql.

You could also try and restarting apache. I think the command for that is

sudo service apache2 reload

sudo service apache2 restart

sudo service mysql restart

Then verify if mysql is running on the socket, run this command to see the process

ps aux | grep mysql

Comment: If you are so new to Linux, then you'll have to google quite a bit on what most of this means, I've been there with being new to a 64 bit version of linux and not knowing how to enter these commands. You'll have to read and Google etc. But run those commands when you ssh into your box/site.

Comment: you'll have to login to your vps via ssh. So whatever system your local computer is on, you do it from a secure shell.  So if you have Windows you'll have to use Putty or Linux, then you'll open terminal. Google them or YouTube it and you'll find a walk-through.

Answer (score 0):

this is simple. Run this on commandline

```
mysql -uroot -p -hlocalhost
sudo service mysql restart
mysql -u root -p
```

I hope that works.